# Stop maven reactor plugin from installing my modules

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

I am using the maven reactor plugin , to build a set of modules from my multi-module project.
The issue here is, that after the packaging is over, then the reactor plugin installs artifacts inside my target directories.

I do not want that, as many parts of the team do not have install permission, and doing an install may lead to a build failure for the same.

Can someone guide me as to how to stop that??

Thanks

EDIT

==========================================

```
                 <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-reactor-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>1.0</version>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>package</goal>
                   </goals>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: How about posting the pom config of the reactor plugin?

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me like you need to add

```
 <configuration>
    <goals>package</goals>
 </configuration>
```

Note: *inside* configuration, not *outside*.